# Ensure web.xml filter-mapping from plugin is appended after springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm attempting to add a very simple `DelegatingFilterProxy` to my Grails application via a custom plugin.

I would like the filter to execute after the `springSecurityFilterChain` filter so that I can make use of certain security-specific information in the custom filter.

I've tried using `loadAfter` and `loadBefore` with different techniques in `doWithWebDescriptor`, but all end with the same result: my custom filter-mapping is always listed before `springSecurityFilterChain`. Below is my current iteration of `doWithWebDescriptor`

```
def contextParams = xml.'context-param'
contextParams[contextParams.size() - 1] + {
    filter {
        'filter-name'('auditFilter')
        'filter-class'(DelegatingFilterProxy.name)
    }
}

def filterMappings = xml.'filter-mapping'
filterMappings[filterMappings.size() - 1] + {
    'filter-mapping' {
        'filter-name'('auditFilter')
        'url-pattern'('/*')
    }
}
```

Is there a correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grails [WebXmlConfig](http://grails.org/plugin/webxml) plugin provides additional features to work with the web.xml file. It hooks into an [event](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/commandLine.html#events), `eventWebXmlEnd` that listens for when the web.xml file is done generating. Once it's done, the plugin will attempt to re-order the servlet filters if necessary. It iterates over all other plugins and looks for a `webXmlFilterOrder` property in the plugin descriptor. If it finds that property, it registers the desired position and after looping over all plugins, rewrites the web.xml file.

The plugin is actually already included as a dependency of the [Spring Security Core](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) plugin, but you should also add it to your own plugin's `BuildConfig.groovy` file:

```
compile ':webxml:1.4.1'
```

So to hook in this functionality, you need to add a `webXmlFilterOrder` property to your plugin descriptor (really just a getter actually). You can throw this right above the `doWithWebDescriptor` closure (youll also need to import `grails.plugin.webxml.FilterManager`):

```
def getWebXmlFilterOrder() {
    [auditFilter: FilterManager.GRAILS_WEB_REQUEST_POSITION + 101]
}
```

The getter returns a Map where the key is the name of your filter and the value is an int describing the desired position in web.xml. WebXmlConfig provides a `FilterManager` class with a few position constants that you can use. In this case, `GRAILS_WEB_REQUEST_POSITION` has a value of 1000.

A quick look at the Spring Security Core plugin descriptor shows that it's putting the `springSecurityFilterChain` filter at `FilterManager.GRAILS_WEB_REQUEST_POSITION + 100`, so by setting your `auditFilter` to anything higher, it will appear below spring security in web.xml.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. There it was, right in front of my face. I kept looking in their plugin descriptor for how they were getting such precise positioning each time. I was so focused on `doWithWebDescriptor` that I missed the 3 little lines above it!